# Can't understand disable button behavior

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm new to android and pretty new to the concept of timing in Java also. I've tried to create a simple app that counts the number of user clicks on the screen in five seconds. After the time ends, I want to disable the button and restart everything when clicking the 'Restart' button.

This is the current code:

```
public void clickCounter(View view){
    ++counter;
    if(showCounter!=null)
        showCounter.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
}
public void clickTimer(final View view) {
   final Button Tap = findViewById(R.id.Tap);
   clickCounter(view);
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
          Tap.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }.start();
        }


public void restartCounter(View view) {
    counter=0;
    showCounter.setText("Tap");
    final Button Tap = findViewById(R.id.Tap);
    Tap.setEnabled(true);
}
```

The button does disable after 5 seconds, but the restart button sometimes enables and then disables it right away (the counter and text changes properly).

I think the problem might be the way I'm using the Timer to do it (maybe I should use threads?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new timer on every button tap. So, when you reenable the button, one of your timers could be expiring, disabling the button afterwards. You should only create a new timer if there is none running.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Tiago Loureino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1122080/tiago-loureiro)'s awesome answer, the problem is that you are creating a new CountDownTimer object every time the `clickTimer()` method is called.

> The button does disable after 5 seconds, but the restart button sometimes enables and then disables it right away (the counter and text changes properly).

This  happens because you have several CountDownTimers executing their `onFinish()` method.

The solution to this problem is to have one single instance of your CountDownTimer. To put that in code, you can declare your CountDownTimer as below:

```
public CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
            Tap.setEnabled(false);
    }
};
```

You can then call `cdt.start()` anytime you want to start your the timer.

Comment: I understan what you are saying but when I tried it the app crashes.

I've implimanted it this way:
`public void clickCounter(View view){
        if(counter==0)
           cdt.start();
        ++counter;
        if(showCounter!=null)
            showCounter.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }
    public CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {
        final Button Tap = findViewById(R.id.Tap);
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        
        public void onFinish() {
            Tap.setEnabled(false);
        }
    };`

Comment: You placed the line `final Button Tap = findViewById(R.id.Tap); ` in the wrong place. Put it outside your CountDownTimer block.

Comment: NullPointerException. The `cdt.start()` executes before the cdt is created

Comment: Move your CDT declaration to your onCreate() method. Make sure it's called before it's used.

Comment: Better still, you can have this as a global variable: `public CountDownTimer cdt;` and then have this in your onCreate(): `cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {...}`

Comment: it works only if i place `final Button Tap = findViewById(R.id.Tap);` within the `cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {...}` in the onCreate(). So just to make sure i understand, cdt is created on create, and from now on i can call it whenever i want using cdt.start() - without creating a new timer everytime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222829/discussion-between-taslim-oseni-and-redyoel).